# how to generated id in odoo 8

Tags: python, sequence, openerp-8

i tried to create generated id in my case. but i cant show this id in view. how to generated id use sequence in odoo 8 ?

my sequence xml like this :

```
    <record id="rsq_code_sequence" model="ir.sequence.type">
        <field name="name">Seed Request </field>
        <field name="code">estate.nursery.request</field>
    </record>

    <record id="seq_request_seed" model="ir.sequence">
        <field name="name">Seed Request</field>
        <field name="code">estate.nursery.request</field>
       <field name="prefix">BPB</field>
        <field name="padding">3</field>
        <field name="company_id" eval="False"/>
    </record>
```

And my .py like this :

```
bpb_code = fields.Char("BPB")

def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    vals['bpb_code']=self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr,uid,'estate.nursery.request')

res=super(Requestplanting, self).create(cr, uid, vals)
return res
```

Comment: what is the error you're getting?

Comment: no , i'm solved for this case.